# Order By And Count with Non-Unique ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table with courses that each have unique ID.

I also have another table that lists each user's progress and a column to associated the progress with a given course.

However, I want to select all rows from this progresses table and order them by the amount of rows a given ID has.

Right now if I use `SELECT count(*) FROM progress GROUP BY courseID` I only get an array of integers for how much times does an ID appear (how many rows), but I don't know which number relates to which ID.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT courseID, count(*) 
  FROM progress 
 GROUP BY courseID
 ORDER BY count(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Course_ID, Student_id, max(colasce(progress,0)) Progress
from Courses
Left Join Students on Courses.ID = Students.Course_ID
group by Course_ID, Student_ID
```